# [WordPress]: PDF file not loading on page

Tags: html, wordpress

I make a page and uploaded a PDF file to display it on my page using Bootstrap with this code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" src="assets\external\filename.pdf" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and it works as expected:

[image]

Now I'm trying to use this with WordPress:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500px"src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?> /assets/external/filename ``.pdf" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But it didn't load. How can I fix this?

I tried this code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500px"src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?> /assets/external/filename ``.pdf" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in `src`: `filename ``.pdf` should be `filename.pdf`.

Comment: "But it didn't load" - what happens instead? Did you check your browser's developer console for error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of mistakes in the code. A more correct method to locate files is by using the function [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/), which also retrieves the current theme folder (either the parent or the child theme, depending on where it is called). You can find more information about the recommended usage of this function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/). Additionally, remember to include spaces between attributes. With that said, you can try using this code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500px" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/external/filename.pdf';?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```